# Handling hardware back button and sending it to WebBrowser control running on Windows Phone

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have a web browser control embedded into a PhoneApplicationPage. I have to handle the hardware back button and force the web browser to go back.

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873086/how-to-handle-the-back-button-on-windows-phone-7) how to handle hardware back button.

How do you force the webbrowser to go to a previous page? The seemingly simple `GoBack()` and `CanGoBack` property on WinForms webbrowser seems to be missing on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable script on the `WebBrowser` control by setting `IsScriptEnabled="true"` you can then use the following to navigate backwards within the browser:

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    browser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
  }
  catch
  {
    // Eat error
  }
}
```

You can find this code (and a bit more) in Shaw Wildermuth's blog post [Navigating with the WebBrowser Control on WP7](http://wildermuth.com/2010/12/24/Navigating_with_the_WebBrowser_Control_on_WP7).

Comment: Dirty but nice looking hack %)

Comment: I still can't predict if I can go back. (Disabling my back button based on history) The old silverlight4 has CanGoBack property, which is missing unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

I've just handled this same question inside [Overflow7](https://stackapps.com/questions/1942/overflow7-stack-exchange-sites-on-windows-phone-7)

I decided to handle this in C# rather than in Javascript. Basically, in my page I've added a stack of Uri's:

```
    private Stack<Uri> NavigationStack = new Stack<Uri>();
```

then I've intercepted the Navigated event of the web browser:

```
    void TheWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationStack.Push(e.Uri);
    }
```

then in the back key press override I try to navigate using the back button if I can:

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationStack.Count > 1)
        {
            // get rid of the topmost item...
            NavigationStack.Pop();
            // now navigate to the next topmost item
            // note that this is another Pop - as when the navigate occurs a Push() will happen
            TheWebBrowser.Navigate(NavigationStack.Pop());
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    }
```

Note that this solution doesn't work perfectly with tombstoning - nor with "ajax" sites - but overall it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Stuart, I think this is a great Idea, I have used a Uri Stack before and for what its worth its a great way of improving the user experience when it comes to using a webbrowser task

Comment: Just in case anyone else gets tripped up on this - the "Navigated" event only fires when the user has ended up on a whole new page (and does not fire for internal #inthispage bookmarks). However, all is not lost - the "Navigating" event does still fire in these circumstances.