# Go Back in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7

I can't find any doucmentation on this. I have a `WebBrowser` control for my C# Windows Phone app, and I would like to have a button to take the user back one page. How can I do this? (I know how to make the button or access the physical back button, the question is just about how to make a function to take the user back one page.

Thanks.

EDIT: Also, if there's nothing to go back to, I'd like to run another function if possible.

EDIT: Tried this: `browser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");`, it's not working for some reason. It just closes the app.

EDIT: Got the above working with `e.Cancel = true;` but how do I restore the default function if there is no page to go back to...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling hardware back button and sending it to WebBrowser control running on Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100538/handling-hardware-back-button-and-sending-it-to-webbrowser-control-running-on-wi)

Comment: Kind of a duplicate but kind of not. That link helped me but there's still a question to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of suggestions [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588315/how-to-check-if-the-user-can-go-back-in-browser-history-or-not) that may work, especially since you don't have to worry about multiple browsers. One way is to use the `history.length' property:

```
if(history.length > 0)
{
  //go back
}
else
{
  //cannot go back so perform other function
}
```

Another way suggested in that thread is to check the referrer. The first page doesn't usually have a referrer:

```
if (document.referrer == "") {
    window.close()
} else {
    history.back()
}
```

Invoke these scripts the same way you invoked the `history.go()` script and see if that works.

Comment: Apparently I've asked this question before. So is this JavaScript or C# then? Looks like JavaScript, I'll have to think of a way to do this...

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it answers the question the opposite way. I need it to check in C# basically...It's a little confusing, but I basically need to figure out how to reverse it...