# Change the textbox(URL) text on back button press in Windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have developed a web browser using the `WebBrowser` API in Visual Studio for a Windows Phone application) I have add a **back** button to this web browser. This is the code that I use for the **back** button to go to previous web page:

```
    private void backOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
          webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");    
    }
```

So now I want to change the textbox(URL) text considering the web page when press **back** button. How can I do that?

Comment: Duplicate.  Look at the answer in C# --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100538/handling-hardware-back-button-and-sending-it-to-webbrowser-control-running-on-wi

Comment: When press the back button I need to change text box text(URL) according to page. that the thing that I asked.

Answer (score 1):

On your `LoadComplete` event on the `WebBrowser` control, look at the `Source` property and sett that into the `TextBox` (that's also useful for redirects).

Comment: HI Shahar Prish thankk you so much, I have done it because of you help.Thanks again.