# prompt confirmation dialog when exit app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an app on wp7.

I hope to prompt a confirmation dialog when user exit app (press back button).

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment

Comment: do you have a **great** reason for needing a prompt?  because as Paul says in the answer below, you won't get prompted on navigating away for any other reason (any notification, or start or search buttons).  Most of the apps that prompt on back annoy me.

Comment: Yes, it is easy. However, considering that you have added a couple of questions about porting iOS code to WP7 it is going to take you a long time to write your application if you ask on StackOverflow each time you want to write some code. I would recommend reading one of teh thoroughly excellent free eBooks on WP7 development. This one is fantastic: [Free ebook: Programming Windows Phone 7, by Charles Petzold](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx)

Comment: I understand why the ability to prompt is there... many times I go deep in an app, and then hit back a bunch of times because I want to get back to the front page of the app.  More than once I've found myself exited from the app w/o intending.

Comment: I am reading the book:Programming Windows Phone 7, by Charles Petzold –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please handle the BackKeyPress button in the Application page to handle the back key press.

In Page.xaml file in the   element add this code

```
BackKeyPress="PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress"
```

it should look like

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage BackKeyPress="PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress"
..//other attributes .. >
```

in event handler you write the code as follows

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
             MessageBoxResult mb =  MessageBox.Show("You want exit the page", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if( mb != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: can we prompt a link to the user?

Comment: You can prompt link, with the help of button with the link text, or the message box text as link and then on press(OK in case of message box) you use the browsertask to open the link. Sample browsertask user is as follows                         WebBrowserTask wtb = new WebBrowserTask();
wtb.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute); 
wtb.Show();

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to catch when the user exits pressing the Back button, but it is not possible to stop the application from being made "dormant" when the user presses the hardware Start button or Search buttons.

Comment: you can get notified when app becomes TombStoned, but you can't cancel that action of course, but that wasn't the question anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can stop back navigation by set `e.Cancel` in back key press event.

In `MainPage.xaml.cs` constructor:

```
OnBackKeyPress += (s, e) =>
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel) == MessageBoxButtons.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    };
};
```

Comment: You can alternatively override the OnBackKeyPress method as shown here: http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=572