# WP7 - Back Button without Navigation Service

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to some how capture the Back Button Event without using the Navigation Service?

A [previous post here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873086/how-to-handle-the-back-button-on-windows-phone-7) describes the the Back Button Events (both the overload of [OnBackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and the event handler [PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.backkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)) only seem to fire when the navigation service is used.

My implementation is:

```
//Prepare the page;
NextPage page = new NextPage();

//When we are ready to transition
page.someData = data;
page.parent = this;
this.Content = page;
```

I'm using this so that I can store the page for use later (essentially so that I can cache it, especially since some of my pages download information from the internet, and so that I can pass it data like above. However, I still need to use the back button to return to the home page.

Is there anyway to trigger the back button while using the above method?

Comment: I assume that you are building a Silverlight app. What do you download? html, xml, pictures, music? Why do you want to store a page? IMO the better idea is to store the data.

Comment: There are a few different things that are downloaded. The biggest issue is that the MainPage is a pivot page and each individual "tab" in the pivot collects some data (like a string) and then opens the relevant tab. For example an app with: a homepage, an XNA game page and a XAML leaderboards page. On the pivot home page, I want to collect a name string. Then I want this name string to be avaliable to both the XNA page and the leaderboards page when the user opens them from the homepage.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `OnBackKeyPressed` event worked with the hardware button. However, can you use `OnNavigatedFrom` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing a whole page to cache the data is a bad idea especially in a limited environment like .Net CF.

- it complicates the app (complicated navigation logic, possible cycles)
- app is limited to 90MB of memory

Store the data in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings when dealing with relatively small amount of data e.g. couple of strings, xml file < 1KB. Otherwise store the data in a file in Isolated Storage e.g music, pictures, huge xmls etc.