# Close App on back button when on certain page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've done some reading and found that one can only close a windows phone app by throwing an un-handled exception that will close the app.

So my question is, how does one do that for the physical back button on the phone?

And how does one have the back button close the app **only if it's on a certain page** ?

So the back button would work as normal, but when it eventually falls on a page called 'noBack.xaml' the back button should close the app.

**EDIT**

Actually on second thought, even just disabling the back button on that page would be awesome...

thanks! :)

Comment: *I've done some reading and found that one can only close a windows phone app by throwing an un-handled exception that will close the app.*  

No, If you start the app and then press back button then the app will close. By pressing the physical back button, one moves down in the stack by removing the topmost entry. When you navigate from startpage to page2.xaml, then startpage is inserted in the stack. Read more about it.

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873086/how-to-handle-the-back-button-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: Throwing an unhandled exception more than likely will cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: You can try clearing backstack, as suggested in an answer, but that is considered bad practice (atleast in WP7), though I know some cases where that would be feasible like in games where back button would show pause menu instead of navigating to previous page. Maybe you should give XNA a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear the backstack when you're on `NoBack.xaml`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
    {
       this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

This way, the next time the user press the back button, it will exit the application.