# How to Ovverride the backkey button including history of webdav file path

Tags: windows-phone-8

hi i'm creating an app using webdav server.Here i'm getting the response from webdav server and i'm binding it to listbox on clicking on that listbox items each and every item having path in webdav. If i went from main root path to particular folder from there if i click on backkey press event app closing and coming out.I want on backkey press root folder should come which should come from subfolder
Please if anyone knew this help me.I knew how to ovveride but it is closing the app.
Please if anyone help highly appreciable.

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
     startRequest();// it is the method which i can retrieve the file structure.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suppose you're building a native WP8 app using Silverlight. There're many totally different ways to build apps for WP8 but you haven't specified your platform. If you're using something different ( JS Web / C# Store / C# Xamarin / JS phonegap / C++ XAML / etc ) my answer is irrelevant.

[See this answer for one way to handle the hardware back key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158783/126995).

In the handler, you need to check whether the currently displayed folder is the root or not.

If it’s the root or empty, you do nothing just return, let the system handle the event, which will close your app.

If your listbox is showing some non-root folder, you set `e.Cancel = true;` and show the content of the root WebDAV folder in your listbox. This way the system doesn't handle the back button event so the app doesn't close, but you do handle so you're showing the root folder in your list.

Comment: if you have snippet please post it i tried like this

Comment: protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            OwnCloud.Data.File fileItem = new OwnCloud.Data.File();
            bool display = true;
            if (fileItem.IsDirectory)
            {

Comment: if (item.Reference == _workingAccount.WebDAVPath)
                {
                    // cannot go up further
                    display = false;
                    //  Debug.WriteLine("from debug" + item.Reference.ToString());

Comment: // MessageBox.Show("From messsagebox" + item.Reference.ToString());

                }
                else
                {
                    fileItem.IsRootItem = true;
                    fileItem.FilePath = fileItem.FileParentPath;

                    /* Debug.WriteLine("From Debug:"+fileItem.FilePath.ToString());
                     MessageBox.Show("From Box:" + fileItem.FilePath.ToString());*/
                }
            }

Comment: else if (!fileItem.IsRootItem)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("value:true");

            }
                                   
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }